# With JIT Compiler what comes first? Translate into machine code or Interpret the bytecode?

Tags: java, jvm, jit

As i know JIT compiles the bytecode into native machine code which can be run faster.So according to my belief the answer of my question should be 1.Translate into machine code 
2.Interpret the bytecode.   As Interpreting the code means executing the code. But i found the answer opposite! Could anyone please explain... Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Once you have machine code for a bytecode sequence (which, as you note, should be faster than interpretation), it makes no sense to keep interpreting that bytecode sequence (*). It's more useful to interpret while compilation is running in the background, or not yet kicked off (for whatever reason -- a common case is: The code hasn't been executed frequently enough to be considered worth compiling).

(*) Actually, some JIT compilers do specialize the machine code so much that it's invalid for some code paths or inputs, and have to fall back to interpretation/re-compiling when those happen. And even other JIT compilers sometimes compile code anew, which may or may not lead to temporarily going back to interpretation. But by and large, if the code applies and is faster (it always should be), there's no point in not using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot delnan. @delnan  Do you mean to say that Once converted into machine code it's cpu responsibility to execute that code not jvm. So Interpreteration of the bytecode should be the earlier than translating in to machine code? There may be a case in which no need of interpration of bytecode as everything will be converted to machine code by jit? Kindly explain....Actually i get confused over this

Comment: @Hriday (1) Yes, the machine code is the run on the CPU. Where else? (2) Yes, this means that interpretation *generally* happens before compilation. But as I write above, reality is more complex and the two may be interleaved. (3) Yes, one *could* end up with *all* code being compiled. But this usually gives worse performance overall (some pieces of code are run so rarely that the time saved by running machine code is less than the time spent compiling it), so it's not really done.